# Android real device can't parse Apps made on Mac OS

Tags: android, eclipse, adk

I'm using Mac version of Eclipse to write codes for Android and it has no problem when I run my apps on AVD but when I use a real Android device It can't install my apps and the Error is:

> There is a problem parsing the package

In addition to that I can't import packages in windows OS.

Does anyone has the same experience or something?
I'm looking for the reason and the cure.

Comment: look for the adk on your file system and copy it externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience these are some things that you could try.

First thing to try is simply cleaning and rebuilding the project. project -> clean

Have you enabled installation of apps from unknown sources?

Have you renamed the apk file manually at all?

The other reason you may be experiencing this is due to conflicting android versions. What version are you packaging the app for and does this match the version that your phone is running? You may have to export a signed version.

Also try adjusting the   android:minSdkVersion to match the version your running. You may be building packages for a newer version than what you are running.